# Is it possible to take a long string value from a JSON file and split it into rows when displayed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have a JSON file which contains long string values.

The JSON is at this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danilovuita/MobileWebDevProject-HitchHike/main/database/HitchDB.json)

Is it possible to split the value from "Inbound" into more rows for a better display in HTML ?

At the moment it displays like this

[image: Website image]

This is the current JS code that does what I have so far:

```
let requestURL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danilovuita/MobileWebDevProject-HitchHike/main/database/HitchDB.json';

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', requestURL);

request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();

const lenHelper = request.response;

request.onload = function() {
  const Hitch = request.response;
  console.log(Hitch);
  for( var i = 0 ; i < Hitch.length;i++){
      appendData(Hitch[i]);
  }
}


function appendData(obj){
  
 // const myHeader = document.createElement('h2');
 // myHeader.textContent = obj.City;
 // $('#Cities').append(myHeader);

   const myDivRow = document.createElement('div');
   myDivRow.className = "row";
   const myDivCol = document.createElement('div');
   myDivCol.className = "col";
   const myCard = document.createElement('div');
   myCard.className = "card mt-3";
   const myCardHeader = document.createElement('div');
   myCardHeader.className = "card-header";
   const myCardBody = document.createElement('div');
   myCardBody.className = "card-body";



   const cityName = document.createElement('p');
   cityName.className = "text-primary"
   cityName.textContent = obj.City;

   const routesInb = document.createElement('p');
   routesInb.textContent = obj.Routes.Inbound;

   //const routesOutb = document.createElement('p');
   //routesOutb.textContent = obj.Routes.Outbound;

  myCardBody.appendChild(routesInb);
  //myCardBody.appendChild(routesOutb);
  myCardHeader.appendChild(cityName);
  myCard.appendChild(myCardHeader);
  myCard.appendChild(myCardBody); 
  myDivCol.appendChild(myCard); 
  myDivRow.appendChild(myDivCol);

  $('#appendable').append(myDivRow);  
}
```

Comment: "Split it into rows" - what condition(s) would you use to determine where the rows start/end?

Comment: I thought of keeping the the rows between | ... |

Comment: So that takes the text and changes the delimiter of the row with "<br/>" , I think it doesn't see it as HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice of taking information, looking at its structure, and separating components is called parsing.

Your 'inbound' data is text in ordinary English, and so we're talking about *Natural Language Parsing*. It's not a topic any of us can cover in a single stackoverflow answer. But you could do some simple things.

(1) using if, check for the length of your text, and only separate rows (paragraphs...) if it is over a certain length.

(2) split it according to key markers. For example, looking for ". " will find sentence separators (provided your text is properly laid out):

```
const routesText = obj.Routes.split('. ')
```

You could look for alternative spearators, e.g. keywords if your text is always structured in the same way, other punctuations, single or double new lines (using '\n' or '\n\n')

(3) process your array of separated elements. If you simply want each sentence on a separate line or paragraph, you would rejoin them, putting a new line between:

```
routesInb.innerHtml = routesText.join(".<br />")
```

or, a paragraph per sentence:

```
routesInb.innerHtml = routesText.map(t=>('<p>'+t+'.</p>')).join("")
```

(4) a process could be more elaborate, e.g. putting two sentences per paragraph, or splitting your text in 2 (or N) paragraphs of roughly equal length, or using keywords at the start of sentences to decide if they start a paragraph... But you will never get the natural impression that the text has been layed out by a writer who understands its meaning.

I didn't ask if you have any control over the original data? Because if so, you should ensure the data contains HTML for layout, or maybe markdown clues (like '\n\n') that you can later replace with HTML layout.

Comment: I have tried it and it works and also, yes, I do have control over the original data.